# SQL Merge Function

Tags: sql, powershell

I am having a problem using the SQL merge function with PowerShell. Whenever I tried to run the PS script, it doesn't show any error messages but there were duplicate IDs being inserted into the tables.

I have 1 database and 1 table (production). The script will create another 1 database and 1 table (temporary) where the updated data will be dumped then the script will perform the SQL merge to update the production database data.

Here's the SQL query format I'm using.

```
    Write-Host "Merging SQL Table Data from $SQLTempTable to $SQLTable"
    $SQLMerge = "MERGE $SQLDatabase.dbo.$SQLTable AS Target
    USING $SQLTempDatabase.dbo.$SQLTempTable AS Source
    ON 
    Target.id = Source.id
            
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
        THEN INSERT 
             (id, first_name) VALUES (Source.id, Source.firstname)

    WHEN MATCHED 
        THEN UPDATE SET
             Target.first_name = Source.firstname

    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
        THEN DELETE;"

    Invoke-SQLCmd -Query $SQLMerge -ServerInstance $SQLInstance -Username $SQLUsername -Password $SQLPassword
```

Here's the result I'm getting. I blurred some info for security purposes, sorry.
[image]

Comment: Is that masked _____id column in the screenshot even the same id as in the merge statement?  Is Target.ID a primary key or not?

Comment: Hi @LukStorms, thanks for the comment. The id column is not masked and it is also not configured as a primary key. There are duplicates from the source (temp database). Do you think it's the root cause?

Comment: duplicate ID's in the source can only be new id's. inserting new dups is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Those duplicates must have been in the source table.

And it's possible only if the ID isn't a primary key in the target table.

**Demonstration**

> ```
> create table TargetTable (id int, first_name varchar(30));
> create table SourceTable (id int, firstname varchar(30));
> ```

> ```
> insert into TargetTable values 
>   (1,'one1')
> , (2,'two1')
> , (2,'two2') -- duplicate
> , (3, 'three1');
>
> insert into SourceTable values 
>   (2,'two3')
> , (3,'three2')
> --, (3,'three3')
> , (4,'four1')
> , (4,'four2')
> ```

> ```
> MERGE TargetTable AS t
> USING SourceTable AS s
> ON t.id = s.id
> WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
>   THEN INSERT (id, first_name) 
>        VALUES (s.id, s.firstname)
> WHEN MATCHED 
>   THEN UPDATE SET
>     t.first_name = s.firstname
> WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE 
>   THEN DELETE;
> ```
>
> ```
> 6 rows affected
> ```

> ```
> select * from TargetTable
> ```
>
> ```
> id | first_name
> -: | :---------
>  2 | two3      
>  2 | two3      
>  3 | three2    
>  4 | four1     
>  4 | four2
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=70abc1e4e42f024fe164ecdac6aa9cc0)*

Comment: But even there's no data yet on the production database, it keeps inserting duplicate IDs using merge function. I've used merge function before but this is the first time I encountered this weird problem

Comment: What if you make the source unique in the merge? F. e. in the fiddle `... USING ( select id, max(firstname) as firstname  from SourceTable  group by id) AS s`